# How to not show a drop down with 'select2' if it has only one choice?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

We want to use select2 in a way such that if we pass only one choice for the dropdown there should be no dropdown. Just the one option selected by default. Is this possible to do ?

Comment: create a demo in fiddle or plnkr.. so that we can try to solve the problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it has to be JS on the clienside:

HTML:

```
<body onload="checkSelectBox()">
```

JS:

```
var select = document.getElementById("idOfYourSelect");
if (select.length == 1)
{
    document.getElementById("outerDiv").innerHTML = select.options[0].text; 
    select.parentNode.removeChild(select);
}
```

This assumes there's a div around it in which you want the text of the option, since you did not bother to share any of your code I can only guess.

Or you could simply disable the select.

```
select.setAttribute("disabled", true);
```